# OCaml partial application for quadratic root

Tags: ocaml

I'm reading Jason Hickey's ["Introduction to OCaml"](http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs134/cs134b/book.pdf) and I'm stuck on an exercise.
[image: Exercise]

I think I understand the example, but I don't get how I can write a function `r a b c` that could pre-compute stuff for fixed values of `b` and `c` with defining `r` like:

```ml
let r b c a = 
(*...*)
```

Second, I don't see what stuff could be pre-computed with only `b` and `c`... Here the most complicated part is taking the square root of `b *. b -. 4. *. a *. c`, which I can't compute without `a`.

Comment: You can compute some terms of the root without `a`. For instance `b*b` or `4*c` are constants if `b` and `c` are bound.

Comment: @Richard-Degenne : true, but the sqrt and the division take so much time that pre-computing one addition and one multiplication will not change the timings. I don't find the answer of this exercise either....

Comment: i'm not sure that the goal is here is to provide an efficient program time-wise, but instead being able to identify the sub-parts of an expression that do not depend on a given variable. I think Richard-Degenne's comment is what you're looking for

Comment: Yeah, this exercise isn't very well-thought. They easily could have come up with better examples of partial application, imho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is two-fold, partially it is about mathematics, partially it is about the partial application (pun intended).

There is one value for which the discriminant formula becomes trivial, it is when `c` is equal to zero. Therefore, we can provide an efficient implementation for it,

```
let discriminant_for_c = function
  | 0 -> fun b a _ -> a *. b /. 2.
  | n -> general_discriminant

let r b c a = (discriminant_for_c c) b c a
```

However, after a second thought, I believe, that it is a typo in the exercise, and it is the `b` variable which is fixed. And indeed, with the fixed `b` we have many more interesting solutions. And will let it as an exercise for you :)

Also, aside from the didactic purposes of this exercise, keep in mind that in real-world applications, it is usually a bad idea to compute the discriminant at all, due to the [catastrophic cancelation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance), and there is a more accurate and stable [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance#A_better_algorithm) to compute quadratic equations.